# Failed to start Informix through Windows services

Tags: windows, informix

I have Informix version 11.50 installed on my Windows machine. According to this [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.expr.doc/expr79.htm), in order to start the server, it should be done through Windows services, look for **Informix IDS - instance_name**. It is supposed to start when Windows is started up, but for my case it is not, and it wasn't started. Thus I start it up manually by double clicking on it, and it prompt me an error:

> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a
>   timely fashion.

May I know is there any solution in order to start up the local Informix DB on windows?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?  Which sub-version of IDS are you using (the letter/number combination such as TC3 after 11.50)?  Have you configured an instance of IDS yet?   Or did you let the installer create a default instance for you?

Comment: Windows Vista and the package that I downloaded is iif.11.50.TC9DE.win2003. I am using the default instance that installer created for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation of Informix in Windows Vista has been failed. Due to the reason this Informix thing is not able to uninstall and not even allow me to configure a database. Even though I have manually delete the whole folder from Program Files, when trying to install a new copy of Informix, it prompt me the "Invalid ISV name" thing which I totally running out of clue with.

I found a post mention that Vista is not a good platform for Informix. Forget about Windows as a Server a.k.a. WAAS.

xD

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check what went wrong in Informix log. It is located in Informix dir and has server name with `.log`  extension (for example `c:\informix\ol_test.log`). In this file there is information about running server like:

```
12:42:36  IBM Informix Dynamic Server Started.
```

Check this file and give us more details if you will not know how to solve reported problems.